# iOS9 how to change back to ALL CAPITAL keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, ios

After using Apple iPhone keyboard for close to 4 years, I'm quite proficient with typing on the keyboard, almost touch typing, while relying on autocorrect.

The new lowercase keyboard totally throws me off.

**How can I get my iPhone with iOS9 to go back to default keyboard where all characters are capitalized?**

[image]

Comment: The new keyboard is also baffling, because every other keyboard, including my current Mac has all capital letters inscribed...

Comment: If you are "almost touch typing", why does the appearance of the keys matter?

Comment: The transition is jarring, as keys shift under my fingers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to **Settings > General > Accessibility > Keyboard** and set the 'Show Lowercase Keys' to off.